# How to position a table correctly?

Tags: tables, positioning

Below is the code I am using, I wish for the paragraph text to be above the table. However everything I have tried hasn't worked including adding a float barrier and using [x] after `\begin{table}`.
The code:

```
\paragraph{\normalfont The international system of units or SI units are a set of standard units agreed upon in 1971. The base units are shown in the table:}
\FloatBarrier
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \scalebox{1.0}{
        \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
            \hline
            Sr. No. & C1 & C2\\
            \hline
            \hline
            1 & Row1Col1 & Row1Col2 \\
            \hline
            2 & Row2Col1 & Row2Col2 \\
            \hline
            3 & Row3Col1 & Row3Col2 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}}
        \caption{SI Base Units}
        \label{SI Units}
    \end{table}
\FloatBarrier
```

The paragraph is positioned below the text when I need it above. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: It's not necessary, and certainly not recommended, to use `\paragraph` instructions for the purposes of creating (typographic) paragraphs. Please feel free to augment your posting to explain how you're creating (typographic) paragraphs at present.

Comment: `\paragraph{` is a section heading like `\section` it is the 4th level so should only be used below `\subsubsection` and only have the title not the full text.  putting `\FloatBarrier` either side of an `[h]` float just force a page break. Finally don't apply `\scalebox` to tables, especially `\scalebox{1.0}{` which is not scaling at all, just forcing a spurious space afer the `{`

Answer (score 1):

What's the purpose of the `\paragraph{\normalfont ...}` "wrapper"? If I remove this wrapper, the `[h]` placement specifier manages to place the table below the paragraph in question just fine.

If, for some reason, you really must use the `\paragraph` wrapper, I suggest you insert an invisible object, say, `\vphantom{.}`, right after it:

```
\paragraph{\normalfont The international system of units or 
SI units are a set of standard units agreed upon in 1971. 
The base units are shown in the table:}\vphantom{.}
```

Comment: I have been using `paragraph{\normalfont...` throughout my whole document where writing information. Otherwise the text is in a bold and looks to similar to my `\sections` and `\subsections` in terms of thickness. I have tried your code and it has fixed my problem by using [H] . Im not to sure why my way wasn't working? But thank you.

Comment: @Horton - I've updated my answer to address your follow-up comment. I still don't understand why you use `\paragraph` instructions "throughout your whole document". Note that `\paragraph` is a LaTeX sectioning command, which can create sectioning numbers if you execute `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` in the preamble. Using `\paragraph` is neither necessary nor recommended for creating ordinary paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you will do. And I have been using LaTeX for less than a week, so I have been using `\paragraph` tags just because I thought this was the best\only way to write information.

Comment: @Horton -- `\paragraph` instructions should be used only if you need to create sectioning units *below* the `\subsubsection` level.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I will look further into this and make changes.

Comment: If you don't want to remove ALL those \paragraph commands, one  can use `\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\par #1\par}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo theoretically you could, but removing the `\paragraph` would be far better.